# Siteminder Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java, authentication, siteminder, javaagents

When trying to deploy my web application on Tomcat 6 I have this error.

It is caused by a SSO pass-through filter in my application.

My SiteMinder version is 6.0.5.35.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.AgentAPI.javaagent_api_init(Lnetegrity/siteminder/javaagent/InitDef;)I
        at netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.AgentAPI.javaagent_api_init(Native Method)
        at netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.AgentAPI.init(AgentAPI.java:509)
        at org.jod.realm.provider.smautenticator.SiteminderBuilderProvider.setupEnvironment(SiteminderBuilderProvider.java:146)
        at org.jod.realm.provider.smautenticator.SiteminderBuilderProvider.setup(SiteminderBuilderProvider.java:136)
        at org.jod.base.realm.AuthenticatorServiceBuilderWrapper.build(AuthenticatorServiceBuilderWrapper.java:47)
        at org.jod.base.service.ApplicationService.build(ApplicationService.java:23)
        at org.jod.ssoagent.JodSsoAgentApplication.start(JodSsoAgentApplication.java:70)
        at it.postecom.webapp.simulatorefido.sso.SSOPassthroughFilter.init(SSOPassthroughFilter.java:68)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates missing native SiteMinder libraries.

As far as I can remember, you have 2 options: SiteMinder can use all-java client implementation or it can be a mix of java + native libs. I recommend going the all-java way - just make sure all necessary jar files are included and the error message should go away.