# UnsatisfiedLinkError while testrun

Tags: java

Having my smjavaagentapi.jar in maven repo path. Still getting a link error. Am I missing any SUPPORTI.jar?

```
Exception from System.loadLibrary(smjavaagentapi) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no smjavaagentapi in java.library.path
FATAL ERROR: Exception from AgentAPI.initialize() java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.AgentAPI.initialize()V
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.082 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.scb.sso.test.CustomAgentTest
```

Comment: For maven related questions. Please post the pom.xml too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Siteminder Unsatisfied Link Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650585/siteminder-unsatisfied-link-error)